# Click event that deletes a record from one table and updates it to another

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I currently have a form that allows a user to fill in fields.

The way the form works:

When the form is completed and the event type button is clicked, the record is deleted from its linked table. Once the recorded is deleted, I want the deleted record to be moved to another table. So in another words, move the record from one table to another, deleting it from its original table.

Is it this possible with a simple SQL statement? Are there any negative aspects trying to achieve this?

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
End Sub
```

The code above works perfectly to delete the record and it knows to delete it from the right table because I used the form wizard to create it. I think i might need to add a insert statement to move the record into another table.

Updated code throws a complie error: Syntax error. Is this due to a line break?

```
Private Sub Command22_Click()

'If Len(CorrectionMadeByContracting & vbNullString) = 0 Then _
   ' MsgBox "Field cannot be left blank"

   ' On Error Resume Next
   ' RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord

    Dim rsSource As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsDestination As DAO.Recordset
    Set rsDestination = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Inquiries")
    Set rsSource = Me.Recordset 'Current form record
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    If Not rsSource.EOF And Not rsSource.BOF
        rsDestination.AddNew 'Add a record to the destination
        For Each fld In rsSource.Fields 'Copy all the fields
            If (fld.Attributes And dbAutoIncrField) <> dbAutoIncrField Then 'Don't copy auto increment
                rsDestination.Fields(fld.Name).Value = fld.Value
            End If
        Next
        rsDestination.Update
        rsSource.Delete 'Delete the record from the source
    End If
```

Comment: Why not leave the records in the table, just flag them as approved/decliened or must be edited (I saw the initial question). Then you can compute the records by their flag. Deleting and then inserting is dangerous, I would do the opposite if I have to as error happens and a doubled row is less bad than a missing one (OK transactions can help, but O don't know your knpwledge, about them). If you use a real RDBMS like SQL-Server you can use triggers. Avoid bad code like `On Error Resume Next`except you know what you are doing and `DoCmd`is ugly too. for deletions use a query (parametrized).

Comment: Agree, 'moving' records is poor practice. Enter a flag value and apply filter criteria.

Comment: There may be several reasons to move records instead of using a flag, such as different locations of the table (a local table for non-approved records, a remote one for approved ones), rights management (only certain users can write to the approved table), a client application that's hard to modify, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using a flag certainly is valid, you can easily move a record using recordsets

(This code assumes equal field names and field types between both the source and destination table).

```vb
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    Dim rsSource As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsDestination As DAO.Recordset
    Set rsDestination = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyDestination")
    Set rsSource = Me.Recordset 'Current form record
    rsSource.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark 'Move recordset to current record
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    If Not rsSource.EOF And Not rsSource.BOF Then
        rsDestination.AddNew 'Add a record to the destination
        For Each fld in rsSource.Fields 'Copy all the fields
            If (fld.Attributes And dbAutoIncrField) <> dbAutoIncrField Then 'Don't copy auto increment
                rsDestination.Fields(fld.Name).Value = fld.Value
            End If
        Next
        rsDestination.Update    
        rsSource.Delete 'Delete the record from the source
    End If
    Me.Requery 'Enforce requery to get accurate record count
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes the two tables are identical. I placed in the code and changed "MyDestination" to my table name. I am getting a complie error: Syntax error. The error highlights the  - If Not rsSource.EOF And Not rsSource.BOF - statement. That statement is also red within my code. I will past my code in the original post.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the update. The code works but only for the first record, after clicking the button for the second record, it says Run-time error '3021' No Current record. It highlights the - rsDestination.fields(fld.name).Value = fld.Value.

Comment: You might want to add a `Me.Requery` after. Since Access tends to skip some checks when deleting this way, you get that error and an invalid record count.

Comment: Thanks erik. Added the Me.Requery, but same issue/error.

Comment: See the current edit. You can remove the `Me.Requery`, but then you will get an inaccurate record count at the bottom.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks again Erik.